# OpenCart User Database [BLOB - 198B]

Tags: php, mysql, blob, opencart

In my OpenCart Database layer I have the follow example

```
FirstName   cart        wishlist
John        [BLOB - 132B]   [BLOB - 0B]
Sarah       [BLOB - 198B]   [BLOB - 19B]
```

What is this BLOB and what can I do to create my own? (I am creating an external register page not using the official one) Can I just use the same fields or leave them blank?

The MySQL record shows (phpMyAdmin):

```
Field: cart
Type: TEXT
Length/Values: blank
Default: Null
Collation: ut8_bin
Attributes: Blank 
Null: Checked
Auto Increment: Not Checked
Comments: Blank
```

Comment: BLOB is a datatype used to store binary data (Binary Large OBject) - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/blob.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cart and Wishlist fields will be automatically filled with saved data for the cart and wishlist respectively for logged in users. They're used to remember what a person has added to cart/wishlist for when they log in again. The cart field will be reset when a person makes a purchase